# Ionic 4 Using MySQL API Authentication Guard Not Working As Expected

Tags: mysql, angular, ionic-framework, observable, ionic4

i am required to make Register And Login process by connecting Ionic 4 to MySQL, the Login and Registration works, but i am having problem on configuring the guard to enable access based on user currently logged in, below is my code at **tabs.router.module.ts** which is the route for first loaded page after user logged in

```
{
    path: 'profile-qr',
    children: [
        {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('../profile-qr/profile-qr.module').then(m => m.ProfileQRPageModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
            role: 'C'
        }
        }
    ]
},
```

below is my code to store login data in local storage during login process **login.page.ts**

```
  async prosesLogin(){
    if(this.loginForm.value.email != "" && this.loginForm.value.password != ""){
      let body = {
        email: this.loginForm.value.email,
        password: this.loginForm.value.password,
        action: 'login'
      };

      this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'user-api.php').subscribe(async data =>{

          if(data.success){

            this.storage.set('session_storage', data.result);
```

below is my code at AuthGuard **auth.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
    const expectedRole = route.data.role;

    this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res)=>{
      if (res == null){
        this.router.navigate([`/home`]);
        return false;
      }else{
        if (expectedRole == res.role) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          return false;
        }

      }
    })
    return false;
}
```

during login as customer@email.com which have a role of 'C' which is customer, i am unable to access any page which have set canActivate : [AuthGuard]

i have tried to copy other code style, which use Observable and Firebase, but i am unable to do so with MySQL because i do not really understand how to write Observable object.

i have checked on the mysql database and the user role are inserted correctly, there are no problem appear on my VSCode,
the problem are only at RBAC

kindly guide and explain on how to write code at **auth.guard.ts**

Comment: First potential problem I see is putting an `async` function as a subscription callback — remove the `async` keyword as it is unnecessary. Is anything stored in your session storage after you log in?

Comment: @WillAlexander yes the comment are stored, i have dump the data using console.log() and the data appear correctly

Comment: The problem have been fixed, i need to set Promise<boolean> | boolean of the function

Comment: ```canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):  Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const expectedRole = route.data.role;

    return this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
      if (res == null) {
        this.router.navigate([`/home`]);
        return false;
      } else {
        if (expectedRole == res.role) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          return false;
        }

      }
    });
    
  }```